# Moment: format using other locale without changing global moment locale

Tags: javascript, internationalization, momentjs, i18next

I have a requirement where I need to format some specific moment objects under a given locale, even if `moment.locale()` is set to something else. Is it possible to somehow invoke `format` in such a way that it uses the static locale only for the current operation?

I know that I can do something like:

```
let oldLocale = moment.locale();
moment.locale('theStaticLocale');
let formattedDate = moment.format('asdasd');
moment.locale(oldLocale);
```

However, this feels completely wrong. What I want instead is something akin to:

```
let formattedDate = moment.format('asdasd','theStaticLocale');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [moment docs - Changing locales locally](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/)

```
var aa = moment();

aa.locale('fr');
aa.format('LLLL');

aa.locale('en');
aa.format('LLLL');
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting global locale:

```
moment.locale('en');
```

Setting a moment object that’ll use global locale:

```
let g = moment();
```

Setting a moment object that’ll use another locale:

```
let x = moment();
x.locale('fr');
```

Printing:

```
console.log(g.format('LLLL')); // Sunday, July 15 2012 11:01 AM
console.log(x.format('LLLL')); // dimanche 15 juillet 2012 11:01
```